# Angular 2 cli run tests on bitbucket pipelines

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to run tests over bitbucket platform with the following configuration:

```
image: node:6.8.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome.list
          - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
          - set -x && apt-get update && apt-get install -y xvfb google-chrome-stable
          - ln -sf /usr/bin/xvfb-chrome /usr/bin/google-chrome
          - npm --version
          - npm install
          - npm test
```

And that's the output:

```
> ng test

Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
13 10 2016 15:26:57.937:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
45:15 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
57:15 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
13 10 2016 15:26:57.945:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
13 10 2016 15:26:57.946:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
13 10 2016 15:26:58.033:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
13 10 2016 15:26:58.421:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

13 10 2016 15:26:58.532:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
13 10 2016 15:26:58.813:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

13 10 2016 15:26:58.814:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
13 10 2016 15:26:59.049:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

13 10 2016 15:26:59.050:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
```

The problem is that karma is not able to start chrome browser. I think the problem happens with any docker enviroment.
How can I run tests in bitbucket pipelines?

Comment: Use a headless browser like PhantomJS instead?

Comment: No, use angular cli default configuration of karma and proactor. Is there any posibility to use chrome, or I have to use phantom?

Comment: Do you particularly *want* to use a non-headless browser? Chrome is the default for Angular CLI projects, but switching to Phantom is trivial (see e.g. my project https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web). Alternatively, have you looked into something like Sauce Labs or installation e.g. Xvfb? This doesn't seem unique to bitbucket pipelines, I'd suggest some broader research.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can use phantom, but I saw in any site that travisCI has chromium installed and users use it to execute tests. Even if you go to angular-cli project, you will see in their travis.yml that tests are run over chromium. Back to your answer, your tests are working properly with these config?

Comment: what problem are you actually trying to solve? Do you just want to get the tests running, or get them running *in Chrome*. Yes, my tests are working, but in TravisCI not a bitbucket pipeline.

Comment: I want to run tests in general, and then in chrome. So both.

Comment: Can you post the karma config you're using?  I'm using a nearly identical pipelines config and it's working for me.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Not sure whether should I stick with Karma and try to get the pipeline executed without errors, or migrate to JEST, which apparently doesn't have this problem. 
All in all, a report containing the unit test results could be useful in my case, maybe a txt file that is automatically attached to the commit in bitbucket...

Answer (score 5):

Try switching your tests over to PhantomJS.

Install PhantomJS Runner https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher

`$ npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher`

Edit your `karma.conf.js` to use PhantomJS

```
// /karma.conf.js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // ...
    plugins: [
      // ...
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      // ...  
    ],
    // ...  
    // browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    phantomjsLauncher: {
      // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered 
      // (useful if karma exits without killing phantom)
      exitOnResourceError: true // Could require proxy if tests access images without /base path
    },
    //...
  });
};
```

This should now run your tests in PhantomJS instead of Chrome.

The default test script also runs watch so you might want to modify your `package.json` test script to be `"test": "ng test --watch=false"`. If you want to have watch run for local development just launch with `ng test` instead of `npm test`.

Answer (score 0):

Try relying on this image instead:

https://github.com/mark-adams/docker-chromium-xvfb

Comment: Test it, and fails

Comment: Yes, cannot start chrome

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but did you remove the lines that add Chrome? (since it comes in the image itself)

Comment: Obviously, ya. when I put the markadams' image, I only use `npm install; npm test --no-watch`. Good try to catch me. xD